BinaryFormatter replacement in VB.NET 8
I recently upgraded from Framework 4.8 to .NET 8.
I have a problem with:
''' <summary>
''' Tools to handle serialization and de-serialization.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Module modSerialization

  Public Sub SerializeBinary(ByVal voSerializable As Object,
                             ByVal vsFileName As String)

    Using oFileStream = New FileStream(vsFileName,
                                       FileMode.Create,
                                       FileAccess.Write)
      Dim oBFormatter = New BinaryFormatter()
      oBFormatter.Serialize(oFileStream, voSerializable)
      oFileStream.Flush()
    End Using

  End Sub


  Public Function Deserialize(ByVal vsFileName As String) As Object

    Using oFileStream = New FileStream(vsFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
      Dim oFormatter = New BinaryFormatter()
      Return oFormatter.Deserialize(oFileStream)
    End Using

  End Function

End Module

The error is

Error (active) SYSLIB0011  'BinaryFormatter' is obsolete: 'BinaryFormatter serialization is obsolete and should not be used. See https://aka.ms/binaryformatter for more information.'.

I added
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>
</PropertyGroup>

to vbproj but the error persists.
I am not an eagle in programming. I would appreciate any ideas on how to fix this.

It depends whether another format is an option for you. The link in the error message lists some alternatives.

Setting <EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization> should transform the error into a warning (which should let you compile). Then you can add <NoWarn>SYSLIB0011</NoWarn> if you want to silent the warning completely.

Have you followed the "BinaryFormatter migration guide"? Longer term you likely need to switch to one of the alternatives (both the migration and risks pages list multiple – if integrating with another system you'll need mutual agrement.

You should take a look at the potential exploits of the binary formatter and see if you need to mitigate them.  You have potential remote code execution vulnerabilities in anything which is using the binary formatter with data potentially provided by a third party.  See e.g. ysoserial for example exploits (beware that this site may trigger security depending on your workplace).

You can also move it to a .NET Standard 2.1 library referenced by your .NET 8 app. There will be no warning. But without the EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization in your .NET 8 application, you will have a runtime error. With it, there is no error or warning.

Not exactly a duplicate but almost the same question for C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76953237/alternatives-of-binaryformatter-in-c

Also see Alois Kraus's serialization roundup here: https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2022/11/23/net-serialization-roundup-2022/  Note that even though it's "binary" the BinaryFormatter performance is quite poor, so you shouldn't dismiss the idea of using one of the faster text formatters.  If you want compact representation, you can always zip it.
